Python project structure when __init__.py at the root folder cause issues, is allowed it to that in general?
I have the following structure. pysbx is a root folder.
pysbx/
    calculator/
        calc.py
        __init__.py
    tests/
        test_calc.py
        __init__.py
    __init__.py

The following code not working by failing import calculator.calc changing to pysbx.calculator.calc is also not working. But python.exe -m unittest discover -v works fine. If I remove __init__.py from the root directory all works OK. So my question is what is the fix and is ok to do that what is the nature of problem. I inherited code which also has __init__.py at root which troubles me, and I want to refactor it but not sure what is the nature of error. After initial research I got impression that this is a bad practice.
import unittest

#from pysbx import calculator
from calculator.calc import Calculator

class TestCalculations(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sum(self):
        calc = Calculator(8, 2)
        self.assertEqual(calc.get_sum(), 10, 'The sum is wrong.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


If the import statements are like import calculator.calc then the top-level __init__.py should not be there. If the import statements are like from pysbx import calculator then it should be there. Both package structures are valid, so the correct approach depends on other things not mentioned in the question.

from pysbx import calculator also cause error No module named pysbx

From which directory are you starting the python.exe for unittest?

from the location of unitest file i.e. pysbx/tests. I actually use IDE just run code there. UPD: I tried from top directory it also issues.
I actually try to make Test Explorer work in VS2022 and it successfully find tests, but when it runs it complains that pysbx module not found. But all works perfect if root __init__.py is removed

I use tox, https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/customize.html#tox-ini - you can add the pythonpaths to your tox.ini file. It is very common to have init.py files located in the application source code folder, in your case pysbx/ - however your tox.ini file should live outside of this.

It looks like it is Visual Studio 2022 bug, I tried vscode and it all works.
